# divide one variable to another?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a variable having query:

```
$countPage="select count(id) from ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` ";
```

which count the number of rows in a table.
I want to divide the count(id) from another variable which is:

```
$recordPerPage= '30';
```

to show 30 records in one page
such that I want this to be happened:

```
$sumPages=$countPage/$recordPerPage;
```

It might be wrong a solution, that's why I am asking. and I want to assign `$sumPages` variable to `$totalPages` variable. please help?

Comment: Two stragies: 1. do the paging on sql level, take a look at the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` options for that), or 2. fetch the whole result set and compute the required page on php level.

Answer (score 0):

the $countpage isnt a real variable yet,you just wrote the query but havent sent anything to mysql driver.
and after you do,you still need to fetch the count(id) variable.

Only then you could do this -

```
$sumPages=$countPage/$recordPerPage;
```

Notice that if you have lets say 40 records it will produce 1.33[3...] to fix that you will need to use ceil function witch will make it 2 as there is no such a thing 1.3 page.

like this -

> $sumPages=ceil($countPage/$recordPerPage);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your query

```
$recordPerPage= '30';

$countPage="select count(id), (count(id)/{$recordPerPage}) from ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` ";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $countPage) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if($result) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   echo 'There are ' . $row[0] . ' records with a total of ' . ceil($row[1]) . ' pages.';
   mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
   echo 'No records found';
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

### EMBEDDED COUNT

```
$sql = "SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM admin_crmf_poc_event_history) records FROM admin_crmf_poc_event_history` where $condition order by event_date asc LIMIT {$startPoint},{$recordPerPage}";
```

Comment: actually i was already using a query like `echo $sql="SELECT * FROM ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` where $condition
order by event_date asc
LIMIT $startPoint,$recordPerPage";` .I want to add #countPage query in it

Comment: you could just do a select as a field.  Will show you by editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

```
$pages=mysql_query("select count(id) from ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` ");

$countPage = mysql_fetch_object($pages);

$recordPerPage= 30;

if($countPage >= $recorPerPage) /*Incase your count page is less then 30  U'll get incorrect value*/

   $sumPages=ceil($countPage/$recordPerPage);
else
   $sumPages=$countPage;
```

take care :)

Comment: actually i was already using a query like echo $sql="SELECT * FROM  admin_crmf_poc_event_history` where $condition order by event_date asc LIMIT $startPoint,$recordPerPage";` .I want to add #countPage query in it